# onTouchStart event triggering Parent OnClick Event in react js

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, gesture, touch-event

Hey i'm Creating a Calendar using reactjs with Custom Drag and Drop . I'm facing issue on Ipad and Touch mobiles . my code is working perfect on desktop but if I open chrome dev tool and change screen resolution to 768px tablet . my events doesn't work in it either. please Help i've used `cursor:pointer` and `e.stopPropagation()` in parent event and child event both but didn't work . i use  `onTouchStart={this.handleTouchStart}`

here is the code i'm using The parent Event is

```js
  Sectiondoubletap(e) {
    debugger
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var timesince = now - this.state.mylatesttap;
    if((timesince < 300) && (timesince > 0)){
 
     // double tap checking
     this._handleDoubleClickSpaltenBody(e)
     console.log("Sectiondoubletap worked")
 
    }
 
    this.state.mylatesttap = new Date().getTime();
 
 }
```

**The child event is**

```js
  handleTouchStart(ev) {
    
    
    ev.stopPropagation();

    console.log("handleTouchStart");
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var timesince = now - this.state.mylatesttap;
    // checking double tap
    if((timesince < 300) && (timesince > 0)){
 
     // double tap checking  
     this._handleDoubleClickItem(ev)
     console.log("Appoinmentdoubletap worked")
 
    }else{
      this.handleDrag(ev);
    }
 
    this.state.mylatesttap = new Date().getTime();

    

   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change

```
e.stopPropagation()
```

by

```
e.stopImmediatePropagation()
```